# Upgrade reference to JQuery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a website that uses - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js. I need to upgrade this to latest version. How can I do it? Is there a URL that I can reference instead of this one?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries

Answer (score 0):

The current latest version of JQuery is 3.6.0

You can see the version from their [download page](https://jquery.com/download/) or any other source

To link it to your website, just use

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I just change reference to this URL or do something else. On another note, what does this utility do?